# Issue with overflow:hidden with transform:skewY

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue where overflow:hidden doesn't seem to be working on a skewed container. I have an issue that requires a box shadow on the outer container with an inner image that extends to the top and bottom of the outer container.

For some reason placing the overflow:hidden on the .skew-container doesn't seem to be hiding the top of the image as expected.

```
.skew-container {
   position: relative;
}

.skew-container:before {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-2.3deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(-2.3deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-2.3deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(-2.3deg);
  transform: skewY(-2.3deg);
  position: absolute;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.skew-container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotate(-2.3deg);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -9px 29px -13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -9px 29px -13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -9px 29px -13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.level-container {
  background-color: green;
}
```

I have attached a jsfiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/eilawen/yy7pL7by/

If anyone could provide any solutions or alternative solutions to the issue it would be appreciated. I have tried using clip-path but unfortunately came across issues applying a box shadow along with positioning the skewed containers right next to each other on the top and bottom.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to hide image with overflow hidden in class `skew-container`?

Comment: Yes, I wish to hide anything that extends outside of the skewed container.